# Missing Operation System when booting from USB-Stick

Tags: live-usb

I am trying to install Ubuntu 15.10 in a laptop and try to make a bootable USB-Stick with the ubuntu iso.

But I always get the error "Missing Operating system" (or boot error).

I tried with different usb sticks, also tried to format them before use (FAT32) and tried different programs to create the usb stick (StartupDiskCreator, Tux-Boot, unetbootin). I also tried with creating the stick on different systems (Kubuntu 15.10 and Ubuntu 15.04). I also tried to download the iso again, in case anything went wrong when downloading, but the md5 checksum is the same.

I also tried to use the usb drive to boot on a different laptop, but I got the same problem.